# Is there a documentation generator for TypeScript Vite/ESBuild projects?

Tags: documentation, typescript

When I switched from JavaScript to TypeScript, I switched the documentation generator from JSDoc to TSDoc as well. However since using Vite and Vitest, which depend on ESBuild and not TypeScript, TSDoc is my only leftover build dependency that depends on TypeScript itself, which is very heavy with over 60 MB. Thus I would like to switch out TSDoc to a documentation generator that integrates with Vite/ESBuild.

So I am looking for an X that is to TSDoc like Vitest is to Jest.

There is Vitepress but that seems to rely on manually generated input files, I am looking for something that automatically generates documentation from code comments like JSDoc and TSDoc.